# Scrapy needs to crawl all the next links on website and move on to the next page

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I need my scrapy to move on to the next page please give me the correct code for the rule,how to write it??

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from delh.items import DelhItem

class criticspider(CrawlSpider):
    name ="delh"
    allowed_domains =["consumercomplaints.in"]
    #start_urls =["http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=delhivery&page=2","http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=delhivery&page=3","http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=delhivery&page=4","http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=delhivery&page=5","http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=delhivery&page=6","http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=delhivery&page=7","http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=delhivery&page=8","http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=delhivery&page=9","http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=delhivery&page=10","http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=delhivery&page=11"]
    start_urls=["http://www.consumercomplaints.in/?search=delhivery"]
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagelinks"]/a/@href',)),           
              callback="parse_gen", follow= True),
    )
    def parse_gen(self,response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//table[@width="100%"]')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = DelhItem()
            item['title'] = site.select('.//td[@class="complaint"]/a/span/text()').extract()
            item['content'] = site.select('.//td[@class="compl-text"]/div/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
spider=criticspider()
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding you are trying to scrape two sorts of pages, hence you should use two distincts rules :

- paginated list pages, containing links to *n* items pages and to subsequent list pages
- items pages, from which you scrape your items

Your rules should then look something like :

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='{{ item selector }}'), callback='parse_gen'),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="pagelinks"]/a[contains(text(), "Next")]/@href')),
)
```

Explanations :

- The first rules matches item links and uses your item parsing method (`parse_gen`) as callback. The resulting responses **do not** go through these rules again.
- the second rule matches "pagelinks" and does not specify a callback, the resulting responses **will** then be handled by these rules.

Notice :

- `SgmlLinkExtractor` is obsolete and you should use `LxmlLinkExtractor` (or its alias `LinkExtractor`) instead ([source](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml))
- The order in which you send out your requests does matter and, in this sort of situation (scraping an unknown, potentially large, amount of pages/items), you should seek to reduce the number of pages being processed at any given time. To this end I've modified your code in two ways :

  - scrape the items from the current list page **before** requesting the next one, this is why the item rule is before the "pagelinks" rule.
  - avoid crawling a page several times over, this is why I added the `[contains(text(), "Next")]` selector to the "pagelinks" rule. This way each "list page" gets requested exactly once

Comment: @ason sorry for the late reply I will run this on my machine and iwll let you know